# I would like to know an option of SmartGit's Log/Graph window for selecting Branch Coloring as default coloring mode

Tags: git, smartgit

I can't find an ability to set Branch Coloring as default mode in configuration. Maybe this ability exists but users can't find it.
I have tried to find it in this settings window [image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, colors are automatically enable on SmartGit.

The [latest version (22.1)](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/whats-new/) boasts some **Log Graph Improvements**:

> The branch colors are now determined by their name, so the same branch will get the same color on each machine.
> Local and remote branches will use the same color, too.
>
> Pushable commits are shown as filled dots, the first-parent history is shown bolder than merged branches, the branch labels now use the same color as their commit lines.
>
> [image: log graph]

And, from 18.1:

> ### Reworked Log and Journal
>
> The default log coloring now uses a dedicated color for each selected refs (unless there are too much).
> This was one of the high-priority topics from [smartgit.userecho.com](https://smartgit.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/6-log-make-branch-line-coloring-easier-to-understand-sg-11160).
>
> [image: https://www.syntevo.com/assets/images/products/smartgit/whats-new/v18-1/log-default-coloring-4f58b1c4.png]

Comment: No, I have a different view of this window on
Version: 21.1.7 #17193, installed: #17144. 
And I suspect that macOS 10.14 is not supported anymore. It's a little bit frustrating thing for me.